# OpenGL inconsistent texture creation

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently having some issues with creating a texture in OpenGL ES 2.0. For some reason, the texture on iOS is offset and the texture on Android is out of alignment. I'm using a `.bmp` image that I got the pixel data from to create the texture.

Errors::iOS:

[image: ios error]

Errors::Android:

[image: android error]

This is how I render out my texture:

```
void PolygonRenderer::renderTextures() {
    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    unsigned char header[54]; // Each BMP file begins by a 54-bytes header
    unsigned int dataPos;     // Position in the file where the actual data begins
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned int imageSize;   // = width*height*3
    // Actual RGB data
    unsigned char * data;
    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(iconPath,"rb");
    if (!file) {
        log("Image could not be opened\n");
        return;
    }
    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) {
        log("Not a correct BMP file");
        return;
    }
    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        log("Not a correct BMP file");
        return;
    }
    // Read ints from the byte array
    dataPos     = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize   = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    width       = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    height      = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

    if (imageSize == 0) {
        imageSize = width * height;
    }
    log("Image size: %d, %d, total: %d", width, height, imageSize);
    if (dataPos == 0) {
        dataPos = 54;
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    data = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    log("Elements read: %d", fread(data, 1, imageSize, file));
    fclose(file);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    GLuint textureId;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    checkForGLError("Add texture:");
    log("Texture created: %d", textureId);
    loadingTexture = textureId;
}
```

The reason I am using RGB, even though `.bmp` saves as BGR is because I use the R channel as opacity and set the color externally. (Also this is OpenGL ES 2.0, which only has GL_RGB and GL_RGBA.)

Rendering polygon excerpt:

```
glUseProgram(shader.get(1));

GLuint projectionLocation =
    glGetUniformLocation(shader.get(1), "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix);
GLuint viewLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader.get(1), "view");

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, loadingTexture);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE,
    &frame.combinedMatrix[16 * loadingPolygons[1].ViewGroup]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loadingPolygons[1].Buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loadingPolygons[1].Buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, loadingPolygons[1].Buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

checkForGLError("In Renderer");
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Vertex Shader Source:

```
std::string textureVertex =
    "attribute vec3 vertexloc;                                              \n"
    "attribute vec3 vertexcol;                                              \n"
    "attribute vec2 vertexuv;                                               \n"
    "varying vec2 TexCoords;                                                \n"
    "varying vec3 textColor;                                                \n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;                                               \n"
    "uniform mat4 view;                                                     \n"
    "void main()                                                            \n"
    "{                                                                      \n"
    "    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(vertexloc, 1.0);   \n"
    "    TexCoords = vertexuv;                                              \n"
    "    textColor = vertexcol;                                             \n"
    "}";
```

Fragment Shader Source:

```
std::string textureFragment =
    "precision mediump float;                                               \n"
    "varying vec2 TexCoords;                                                \n"
    "varying vec3 textColor;                                                \n"
    "uniform sampler2D text;                                                \n"
    "void main()                                                            \n"
    "{                                                                      \n"
    "    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture2D(text, TexCoords).r);  \n"
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;                     \n"
    "}";
```

Edit: Added the second loadingPolygon value:

```
w = 250;
h = 43;
x = sWindowWidth / 2 - w / 2;
y = - sWindowHeight / 4 - h / 2;
temp = {
    x,              y + h,          0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    0, 1,

    x,              y,              0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    0, 0,

    x + w,          y,              0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    1, 0,

    x,              y + h,          0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    0, 1,

    x + w,          y,              0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    1, 0,

    x + w,          y + h,          0.3,
    textureColor.x,    textureColor.y,    textureColor.z,
    1, 1
};
polygonRenderer.addLoadingPolygon(temp);
```

Edit 2: Android eglconfig:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

Edit 3: Creating a shader:

```
GLuint Shader::LoadShader(std::string vertexSource,
    std::string fragmentSource, std::map<int, std::string> attribs) {

    GLuint vertexShader = LoadSubShader(vertexSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = LoadSubShader(fragmentSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    if (vertexShader == 0 || fragmentShader == 0)
        return 0;

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    if (program == 0) {
        log("Error compiling shader");
        return 0;
    }
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    std::map<int, string>::iterator it;
    for(it = attribs.begin(); it != attribs.end(); it++) {
        glBindAttribLocation(program, it->first, it->second.c_str());
    }

    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);

    if (!linked) {
        log("ERROR");
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

        if (infoLen > 1) {
            char infoLog[512];
            glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            log("Error linking program: %s", infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteProgram(program);
        return GL_FALSE;
    }
//    glDetachShader(program, vertexShader);
//    glDetachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    return program;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `glBindAttribLocation()` before linking the shader program? Or how do you know that the attribute locations will be 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: Yes I am. I can include that in the main code area if you need.

Comment: Does your input data have some kind of padding at the end of each row of data? You are telling GL that the data is densely packed, but it isn't always the case with bitmaps (especially RGB data, as 3 bytes is an awkward number of deal with).

Comment: This may be the issue, yes, since I am looking at the individual pixel data and it is vastly different from loading the bmp in iOS and android. In ios, there are sets of 3 channels, easily discernible. In android, there seem to be sets of four and it interpreted the width, height, and size of the image differently. Why would it do this?

Comment: And I don't know if there is padding or not, I used gimp to export to .bmp and chose to export as R8 G8 B8. I'm currently thinking of interpreting the image non-natively, for consistency and then passing the pixel data to the native components.